How do I solve the booting issue with qemu vexpress-a9 zImage?
I'm studying about the boot loader.
I aim to build the Linux kernel and boot the zImage on qemu-system-arm. First, I installed a cross-compiler for vexpress-a9. Using crosstool-ng, I installed arm-cortexa9_neon-linux-gnueabihf, but I changed the target vendor name from cortexa9_neon to hello. After building, the following executable files were created in x-tools/bin.
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-addr2line     arm-linux-addr2line
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ar            arm-linux-ar
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-as            arm-linux-as
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-c++           arm-linux-c++
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-c++filt       arm-linux-c++filt
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-cc            arm-linux-cc
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-cpp           arm-linux-cpp
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ct-ng.config  arm-linux-ct-ng.config
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-dwp           arm-linux-dwp
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-elfedit       arm-linux-elfedit
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-g++           arm-linux-g++
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc           arm-linux-gcc
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc-13.2.0    arm-linux-gcc-13.2.0
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc-ar        arm-linux-gcc-ar
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc-nm        arm-linux-gcc-nm
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc-ranlib    arm-linux-gcc-ranlib
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcov          arm-linux-gcov
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcov-dump     arm-linux-gcov-dump
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcov-tool     arm-linux-gcov-tool
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gprof         arm-linux-gprof
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld            arm-linux-ld
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld.bfd        arm-linux-ld.bfd
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ld.gold       arm-linux-ld.gold
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ldd           arm-linux-ldd
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-lto-dump      arm-linux-lto-dump
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-nm            arm-linux-nm
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-objcopy       arm-linux-objcopy
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-objdump       arm-linux-objdump
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-populate      arm-linux-populate
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-ranlib        arm-linux-ranlib
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-readelf       arm-linux-readelf
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-size          arm-linux-size
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-strings       arm-linux-strings
arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-strip         arm-linux-strip


Next, I downloaded Linux version 6.6.33 and built it using the following commands.
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-hello-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-

I then attempted to boot using the zImage with the following qemu command. However, the outcome was as follows.
qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a9 -m 128M -kernel zImage -nographic -append "console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/mmcblk0 ro"

There is no progress at all. I expected the kernel to load and potentially produce a panic log, but nothing is being outputted.
Thanks for your helps!...
ps. I tried another command to build the kernel.
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-hello-linux-

But there is no output log too.

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

No output is the typical failure mode for "kernel crashed early in bootup or was not configured correctly for this machine type". Chances are high that your problem is that your kernel config is incorrect or missing some relevant device option. You don't say how you configured the guest kernel.
